# ветвление графиков и расчетов на delphi

Tags: delphi

есть уравнение к примеру 
Y^2=4
y=+-2
и если брать больше точек то получается что решения расходятся на 2 отдельных пути
так вот 
подскажите как такое правильно реализовать что б задаваемое исходное параметрическое уравнение и диапазон после просчетов превращался в 2 отдельных массива решений 
у меня нет идей просто как разделять результаты

Comment: Честно говоря, задание не очень понятно. К примеру, куда подставлять "больше точек"? Возможно, в исходное параметрическое уравнение, но где оно?

По поводу ветвления, в один массив пишем значения с плюсом, в другой - с минусом. При общем виде квадратного уравнения: в один массив пишем иксы1, в другой - иксы2

Comment: уравнений много, очень много
больше точек - это когда берется x по диапазону и подставляется в одну и туже функцию - вот что я хотел сказать 
 в один массив пишем значения с плюсом, в другой - с минусом - мне именно этот момент интересен, я не понимаю как разделять и даже получать такие значения, еще не разу не брал расчеты с корней квадратных

Comment: Примерно так:

    d=sqrt(x);
    y1[i]=d;
    y2[i]=-d;